# How to modify py2app setup.py to allow import of my own modules?

Tags: python, py2app

I'm creating an app on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.4, system python 3.7) using py2app with python 3.7 and the IDLE IDE. The app is called network_plotter.py and calls functions in another file, network_tools.py. Currently both files reside in the same directory,

Including the line import network_tools at the start of network_plotter.py allows me to run the file network_plotter.py in IDLE with no problems.

Now to create the network_plotter app Following the py2app documentation instructions, I created my setup file, which looks like the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['network_plotter.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I need for the network_tools.py script to be included in the final app distribution, and I'm not sure what to modify above to do so. I've tried inserting after app=APP, each of the following lines, none of which works:

1. py_modules=['/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/network_tools']
2. ext_modules=['/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/network_tools.py']
3. scripts=['/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/network_tools.py']

In each case, the final app will not run, either when I double-click on it or try running it from the terminal. The latter approach leads to the error message, "No module named 'pygments.lexers.python"